# Output results from a jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery

I'm calling a web service using jquery's ajax method and it seems to work since the 'success' function is executed. I need to output the raw results returned, but when I use alerts, the messagebox shows the output as:

```
event=''
XMLHttpRequest=success
ajaxOptions=undefined
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I output the raw results?

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://mysite/service/lists.asmx",
type: "POST",
dataType: "xml",
data: soapEnv,
contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
success: function(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions){
 alert("event= "+event);alert("XMLHttpRequest= "+XMLHttpRequest);
 alert("ajaxOptions= "+ajaxOptions);},
error: function(xhr) {
 alert('Error! Status = ' + xhr.status);}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using firefox with firebug, you can look under the NET tab.

Click NET clear it out.
Do your AJAX call and click on the + to expand the item.
Look under the Response tab to see what came back.

Side note: you can also look at the request as well.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use firebug to check the response format

Comment: Ah, you just want to SEE it... I thought you wanted to output it for some usage other than manual inspection.   Firebug is the best option for this.

Answer (score 4):

The first issue here is that your arguments are wrong for the `success` callback.

The args are actually as follows:

```
function (data, textStatus) {
    this; // the options for this ajax request
}
```

So, in your code, `event` is actually the data (jQuery will have converted responseXML for you and stuck it in this variable), and your `XMLHttpRequest` is actually the textStatus.

So you'd want to do something like this

```
function(data, status) {
    alert('response: ' + data);
}
```

**If you want the XMLHttpRequest object directly:**

```
var xhr = $.ajax({ /* blah */ });
```

Then you can look at `xhr.responseText` when the call is complete to see the raw result.   It's probably better to use jQuery's data param if possible though.

For more info the [jQuery ajax docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options).